# in the attached code i am able to fetch data from 1 file but i want to fetch the data from multiple excel files which i am selecting

Tags: vba

In the below code i am able to fetch data from 1 file but i want to fetch the data from multiple excel files which i am selecting.
can anyone please help me how i can get through with it.

```
Sub CopySheet()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim flder As FileDialog
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim FileChosen As Integer
    Dim wkbSource As Workbook
    Dim wkbDest As Workbook
    Set wkbDest = ThisWorkbook
    OpenFile:
    Set flder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    flder.Title = "Please Select an Excel File"
    flder.InitialFileName = "c:\"
    flder.InitialView = msoFileDialogViewSmallIcons
    flder.Filters.Clear
    flder.Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xlsm*"
    MsgBox ("Select a folder and then a file to open.")
    FileChosen = flder.Show
    FileName = flder.SelectedItems(1)
    Set wkbSource = Workbooks.Open(FileName)

    wkbSource.Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Copy
    wkbDest.Sheets("Master").Cells(wkbDest.Sheets("Master").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    wkbSource.Close savechanges:=False
    If MsgBox("Do you want to open another workbook?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then GoTo OpenFile
  End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much really appreciate for your fast and correct response. The code work really well

Answer (score 0):

Please, test the next updated code:

```
Sub CopySheet()
    Dim flder As FileDialog, FileName As String, FileChosen As Integer
    Dim wkbSource As Workbook, wkbDest As Workbook, i As Long
    
    Set wkbDest = ThisWorkbook
OpenFile:
    Set flder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
     flder.Title = "Please Select Excel files"
     flder.InitialFileName = "c:\"
     flder.InitialView = msoFileDialogViewSmallIcons
     flder.Filters.Clear
     flder.Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xlsm" 'no need of ending *. Nothing can come after xlsm...
      MsgBox ("Select a folder and then files to open and process.")
     flder.AllowMultiSelect = True
     FileChosen = flder.Show
     If FileChosen = -1 Then
         Application.ScreenUpdating = False
         For i = 1 To flder.SelectedItems.count
            FileName = flder.SelectedItems(i)
            Set wkbSource = Workbooks.Open(FileName)
        
            wkbSource.Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Copy
            wkbDest.Sheets("Master").cells(wkbDest.Sheets("Master").rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            wkbSource.Close savechanges:=False
        Next i
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    If MsgBox("Do you want to process other workbooks?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then GoTo OpenFile
End Sub
```

Comment: @Juned Kadri Does your comment address to me? If yes and you want me being notified, please tag me (@FaneDuru). Or better, comment **bellow my answer**. And we here, when somebody answers your question in a convenient way, tick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer** (here). In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue, will know that the code works as it should...